# Can we include the Neo4j application output in our Front-end Angular&NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, neo4j

I want to include the output of the Neo4j application in my Angular Front-end application. (I shall use Nodejs also for backend if required)Is there such a provision ?

Can you please let me know how to include only the middle portion of graph-diagram out of the entire UI of Neo4j-

[image: neo4j]

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch data from Neo4j HTTP api (Not sure about bolt), you can actually fetch graph relationship data.

Once you get that data, it is just a matter of plugging that into any graph visualization libraries available to create your own.

Here is some information along with some examples of [Neo4j Graph Visualization](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/)

Comment: Hi Himanshu, Can you please help here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718635/getting-error-response-with-status-404-not-found-for-url